# Mark cross-site cookies as Secure to allow setting them in cross-site contexts

Tags: javascript, cookies, next.js, axios

In nextjs using nookies, in browsers with chromium, it is giving the error that is in the title and it is not saving the cookie.

The website is hosted and with SSL/HTTPS.

Already tried:

sameSite = None
secure = true

==

sameSite = Lax

==

sameSite = Strict

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kc5Ji.png)

[axios config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfJ4j.png)

[auth context signin function with set cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ld9gY.png)

Comment: I think it would help if you add your request code

Comment: Next.js fullstack, api routes and prisma.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved, I found that my deploy was not working and the version that was online was old without sameSite="None" and Secure=true

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask for

```
samesite=none;secure;httponly
```

Not using **secure=true;** I added HttpOnly to ensure it is not included over HTTP.

For it to work, you must also use HTTPS and not HTTP, which is a requirement to be able to set samesite=none.

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic: [Debugging cookie problems](https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/)

Comment: Same error: 
    
    `res.setHeader(
      "Set-Cookie",
      "reborn.auth.token=${token}; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure; HttpOnly; Max-Age=31536000"
    );`

Comment: For it to work, you must also use HTTPS and not HTTP. Are you using HTTPS?